# Work with 'echo' command line in Python code

Tags: python, echo

I tried to use Python with command line parser 'kakasi' together. Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
text = 'スッキリわかる Java入門 実践編 第2版'
cmd = "echo $text | iconv -f utf8 -t eucjp | kakasi -i euc -w | kakasi -i euc -Ha -Ka -Ja -Ea -ka"
os.system(cmd)
-------------------
```

The result is empty line as below:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Actually, the result should be like this:

```
sukkiri wakaru Java nyuumon jissenhen dai 2 han
```

I need a help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text` is a variable known to the python interpreter only; the shell you execute your command in has no idea what `$text` is (it will evaluate to an empty string).

you could try this:

```
cmd = "echo '{}' | iconv ...".format(text)
```

that way you get your string to the command you want to execute. (can't test if there are other things that do not work...)

(side note: i like the [sh module](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) for this kind of thing. it is not in the standard library though).

Comment: Thanks. It is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You should need to use [String formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

**SOLUTION :**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
text = 'スッキリわかる Java入門 実践編 第2版'
cmd = "echo {} | iconv -f utf8 -t eucjp | kakasi -i euc -w | kakasi -i euc -Ha -Ka -Ja -Ea -ka".format(text)
os.system(cmd)
```